# module 'website.management.commands.updatemodels' has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-templates

I am finding a problem while executing this code on my app 'website' using django

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr15N.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWMP6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not add code as screen shots as it is incovenient to access.

here is the mistake I can see:

1. the class name needs to be class Command(BaseCommand):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
 ....
```

Comment: thanks sir, i still have a problem knowing that I've changed the query to :
for Product_Name,Product_Price in zip(df.Product_name,df.Price): 
            models=Product.objects.get(Product_Name=Product_name,Product_Price=Price)
            
            models.save()

Comment: and the problem is http://prntscr.com/26ch1tz , here is my excel database : http://prntscr.com/26ch20v

Comment: its a typo in the Query ... should be  Product_Name=Product_Name

Comment: thanks sir sorry for the disturbance

Comment: please can you reply on my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70672500/xxxx-matching-query-does-not-exist

Comment: Sorry for my mistake: you wanted to create a new instance so your line was perfectly right: model=Product(field1=....). I corrected my answer. Hope everything is ok now.